# create an append method

Tags: java, arrays, append

I'm doing a project that requires me to create an append method.

This is what the instructions say:

These methods should create a new double array containing exactly those
elements of data followed by those of the array passed as a parameter. A reference to this array
should be assigned to data. If the parameter is null, then the method should do nothing (no new
array created)

so far this is my code:

```
public void append(double [] d) {

        if (data != null) {

        double[] newDataArray = new double [data.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            newDataArray[i] = data[i]; 
        }

        } else {

        }

    }
```

I'm testing it using this main method:

```
double[]    data1   =   {};
double[]    data2   =   {   25  };
float[] data3   =   {};
float[] data4   =   {   25  };
int[]   data5   =   {};
int[]   data6   =   {   50  };
long[]  data7   =   {};
long[]  data8   =   {   12  };
Stat    stat1   =   new Stat();
stat1.append(data1);
stat1.append(data2);
stat1.append(data3);
stat1.append(data4);
stat1.append(data5);
stat1.append(data6);
stat1.append(data7);
stat1.append(data8);
data1   =   null;
stat1.append(data1);
System.out.println("stat1   data    =   " + stat1.toString());
System.out.println("stat1   min =   " + stat1.min());
System.out.println("stat1   max =   " + stat1.max());
System.out.println("stat1   average =   " + stat1.average());
System.out.println("stat1   mode    =   " + stat1.mode());
System.out.println("stat1   variance    =   " + stat1.variance());
System.out.println("stat1   standard    deviation   =   " + stat1.standardDeviation()   +   "\n");
```

This is my output:

```
stat1   data    =   [0.0, ]
stat1   min =   0.0
stat1   max =   0.0
stat1   average =   0.0
stat1   mode    =   0.0
stat1   variance    =   0.0
stat1   standard    deviation   =   0.0
```

However the output should be:

```
stat1   data    =   [25.0,  25.0,   50.0,   12.0]
stat1   min =   12.0
stat1   max =   50.0
stat1   average =   28.0
stat1   mode    =   25.0
stat1 variance  =   189.5
stat1   standard    deviation   =   13.765899897936205
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`data` isn't defined anywhere, even though it is used in your `append` method; nor does it get assigned to in your method.